# "'child.parent == this': is not true.". I getting this error when a put a textfield inside a listview. (Flutter)

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a textfield inside a function:

```
Container header(int position) {
return Container(
  height: 50.0,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.75)),
  padding:
  new EdgeInsets.only(top: 7.5, bottom: 7.5, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
  child: new Container(
    child: new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        //MEAL TF
        mealNameTextField(position),

        //TIME TF
        timeTextField(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);}
```

mealNameTextField():

```
Container mealNameTextField(int position) {
return new Container(
    width: 160.0,
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: new TextField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        hintText: "Meal Name #${position.toString()}",
        border: border(),
        hintStyle: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
        fillColor: colorBackgroundTable,
        filled: true,
      ),
    ));}
```

This text field (the header function) is inside a listView:

```
child: new ListView.builder(

    controller: scrollController,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 20.0),
    itemCount: numMeals,
    key: key,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) => Padding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
      child: new Container(
        width: 320.0,
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
                height: double.maxFinite,
                color: colorBackground,
                child: new ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[

                    header(position),
                    bodyListFood(),
                    new SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                    buttonAddFood(),
                    new SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                    nutriInfo(),
                    new SizedBox(height: 24.0)
                  ],
                ))
          ],
        ),
```

But, when I change de value of textfield the following error appears:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMw0i.png

This error only happens when texfield is inside of the listview. Outside it, works perfectly.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: What's the point of having two vertical list wrapped into each others?

Comment: In this case, the listview works like a column widget